# IOS Is there a way to send user to particular view after tapping "view" on notification?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, push-notification

I am using push notifications in my app and I would like to send user to particular view, not the view he last saw. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement the appropriate [AppDelegate messages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4).

Specifically, you will receive the APNS payload on the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

You might also receive the payload in a different message, `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` if the application is active.

Then when you know that your app was launched because the user touched a notification, you can direct him to a specific view accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you have control over what the user sees while app is starting app (opening animation). After the app is fully active, you can send him wherever you want to by opening proper view controllers, setting proper tab, etc...